# TypeError: scatterplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Tags: python

```
sns.scatterplot(data['value'],data['time'],hue=data['crop_type'])

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e3c53ad1625e> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 sns.scatterplot(data['value'],data['time'],hue=data['crop_type'])

TypeError: scatterplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

I want a solution to fix this error

Comment: The documentation shows the correct syntax for a very similar example: `sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time")` https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the original code with:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=data, x="value", y="time", hue="crop_type")
```

Or:

```
sns.scatterplot(x=data['value'],y=data['time'],hue=data['crop_type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This error depends on how you're storing your data as I have stored my data in the following manner:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/pathway for your dataset')
```

So when I wrote the code in the following manner:

```
sns.scatterplot(df['cgpa'],df['resume_score'],hue=df['placed'])
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: scatterplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

so I rewrote it as:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x="cgpa",y="resume_score",hue="placed")
```

If you're not storing your data in df, then the code will change like this:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=pd,x="cgpa",y="resume_score",hue="placed")
```

and this worked for me. You can check out the [link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) for the whole documentation, where it's explained with examples.